# Save checked row of one dataGrid into another dataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a simple datagrid which Stores the data returned in json format in it. I have added unbound checkbox column to it. Now I want to Store only the checked rows in another datagrid. How should I proceed.

**My Code**

```
  protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    foreach (DataGridItem item in this.gv1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chkBox =
           (CheckBox)item.FindControl("ChkRows");

        //If it's selected then add it to our new Datagrid
        if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
        {
            //save
        }

}

}
```

**datasource for 1st grid**

```
SearchAPIRequest.defaultApiKey = "samplekey";
            SearchAPIRequest request = new SearchAPIRequest(rawName: txtUser.Text);

            try
            {
                SearchAPIResponse response = request.Send();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("Website");
                dt.Columns.Add("first");
                dt.Columns.Add("last");
                dt.Columns.Add("jobs");
                dt.Columns.Add("dobs");
                dt.Columns.Add("educations");
                dt.Columns.Add("addresses");
                dt.Columns.Add("images");

                dt.Columns.Add("URL");

                for (int i = 0; i < response.Records.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dr["Website"] = response.Records[i].Source.Domain;
                    dr["First"] = response.Records[i].Names[0].First;
                    dr["Last"] = response.Records[i].Names[0].Last;
                    dr["jobs"] = response.Records[i].Jobs.Count > 0 ? response.Records[i].Jobs[0].Display: "";
                    dr["dobs"] = response.Records[i].DOBs.Count > 0 ? response.Records[i].DOBs[0].DateRange.Start.ToString() : "";
                    dr["images"] = response.Records[i].Images.Count> 0 ? response.Records[i].Images[0].Url:"";
                    dr["educations"] = response.Records[i].Educations.Count > 0 ? response.Records[i].Educations[0].Display : "";
                    dr["addresses"] = response.Records[i].Addresses.Count > 0 ? response.Records[i].Addresses[0].Display: "";
                    dr["URL"] = response.Records[i].Source.Url;

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                gv1.DataSource = dt;// response.Records[0].AllFields.ToList();
                gv1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I just want to know how should i transfer the Checked rows to a new datagrid

Comment: What is the DataSource of the other grid? Btw, you can edit your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: I didnt knew that I am new Here. I make json get request and store the response in the grid.

Comment: I edited the question and added the datasource.